# php yii unable to login using useridentity component

Tags: php, yii

Here is my authentication controller

```
class AuthController  extends Controller
{

    public function actionLogin()
    {
        $model = new LoginForm;

        $post = Yii::app()->request->getPost('LoginForm');
        // If form is submitted
        if($post) {
            $identity = new UserIdentity($post['username'], $post['password']);

            if($identity->authenticate()) {  // loop enters but could not get id
                echo Yii::app()->user->id;
                echo Yii::app()->user->getId();
            } else {
                echo 'failed';
            }
            //exit;
        }
        $this->render('login', array('model' => $model));   
    }
}
```

Here is my UserIdentity.php

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{


    private $_id;

    public function authenticate()
    {   
        $user = SchLogins::model()->findByAttributes(array('username' => $this->username));
        if(is_null($user)) {
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        } else if($user->password != $this->password) {
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        } else {

            $this->_id = $user->id;

            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }

        return !$this->errorCode;
    }


    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

In the above code I am having problem in getting user id (i.e) `Yii::app()->user->getId();` this returns nothing and what wrong I did the above code

Comment: Does `Yii::app()->user->id` return anything?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `LoginForm` instance `$model` but you never use it to actually login. If you are using the standard `LoginForm` model then it is what interacts with the `UserIdentity` class. It should be this:

```
if($post) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];

    if ($model->validate() && $model->login()) {  // loop enters but could not get id
        echo Yii::app()->user->id;
        echo Yii::app()->user->getId();
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
    //exit;
}
```

If you look at the `login()` function of LoginForm you will see it calls `Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);` which is what actually sets the `Yii::app()->user` which with your method was being skipped.